# RxJS ReplaySubject observer length doesn't increase after next

Tags: javascript, rxjs

According to my current understanding of `ReplaySubject` in RxJS, the code below should work:

```
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs/ReplaySubject';

private dataObs = new ReplaySubject(1);

  get_posts(value) {
    console.log(this.dataObs.observers.length);
    if (this.dataObs.observers.length) {
      console.log('Going cache');
      return this.dataObs;
    } else {
      console.log('Going live');
      return this.http.get(`endpoing here`)
        .map((res) => {
          this.dataObs.next(res);
          console.log(this.dataObs.observers.length);
          return res;
        });
    }
  }
```

But it doesn't, which I don't understand.

The `this.dataObs.next(res)`, based on my current understanding should make `this.data.observers.length` to be `1`, thus allowing the first if block condition to pass. But that isn't happening.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that your observers list is empty is because there are no observers of your observable.

Your `next()` emission does not add any value to the observers list, it just adds an emission to be sent to all observers. If you want your observer list to be non-empty, subscribe to your subject:

```
this.dataObs.subscribe();
this.dataObs.observers.length != 0; // => true
```